# R-ggplot plot median with ranked values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a plot of the median of my ranked data. And under this plot I'm trying to plot the ranked value.

example data:

```
test=data.frame(a=rep(seq(-5,5,by=0.1),each=1,length.out=101),b=runif(101, min=-5, max=5))
test$range=rep(seq(1, 101, by=1), each=1,length.out=length(test[,1]))
```

So I'm trying to plot only the median.
I tried :

```
ggplot(data= test) + stat_summary(
    mapping = aes(x = range, y = b),
    fun.y = median)
```

But I got a Warning message : Removed 101 rows containing missing values (geom_pointrange).

I got it with this command :

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = range, y = b, color = b )) + 
  geom_line(size = 0.5)  +
  geom_smooth(aes(color=..y..), size=1.5, method =                                         "loess", se=FALSE) +
  scale_colour_gradient2(low = "green", mid = "yellow" , high = "red", 
                     midpoint=median(test$b))
```

[image: median]

but it's not exactly what I want, I want only the median.

Also I want to plot the value of test$a under this plot. But I have no idea of how can i do this :

[image: gradient_scale]

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

So I'm confused by some things. First, the first plot you show has `b` on the y-axis, yet the code implies you're plotting `a` on the y-axis. So do you want the median of `a` or `b`? Also, I don't understand what the `range` variable is supposed to do.

That said, maybe this will be of some help. I assumed the variable of interest was `b`. We can make something resembling your min-to-max illustration by plotting `b` as a function of its rank. Next we can add a horizontal line at the height of the median.

```
ggplot(test, aes(rank(b), b)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = median(test$b))
```

Which gave me a plot like this:

[image]

Hope this was of some help!

Comment: Sorry for the code. I make a mistake while I was trying to resolve my problem and paste the wrong code... Thank to notice me that.
range is use to get the rank of my data. I want to plot the median of my data relative to the rank. And under a kind of gradient plot where we can see that a is increasing